# Two arrays to one chunked

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a two arrays and need to get one from them. `array_merge`, `array_map` etc. Doesn't give right result.

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array2 = [a,b,c,d,e];
```

I need `$array3 = [[1,a], [2,b], [3,c]]`...

What is the best way to get that result?

Comment: is the length of this two arrays are equal? if so use `for` loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `array_map(null, $arr1, $arr2)` you can achieve the result.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
php > $q = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
php > print_r($q);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => c
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => d
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => e
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop approach is the following:

```
<?php
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array2 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$array3 = array();
if(count($array1) == count($array2))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++)
    {
        $array3[] = [$array1[$i],$array2[$i]];
    }
}
else
{
    die("SIZE MISMATCH");
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array3);
```

And the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => c
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => d
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => e
        )

)
```